# Que signifie « une » dans cette phrase?

Tags: sens

[image]

Voici un extrait du livre *Introduction à la philosophie de l'histoire* de Raymond Aron. Le titre de ce chapitre est *philosophies de l'histoire et idéologies.* Ces anticipations sont les prévisions du marxisme, par exemple le triomphe inévitable du prolétariat. Que signifie « une » dans cette phrase?

Comment: Je ne connais la pensée de Raymond Aron que de très très loin et je ne garantis pas que mon interprétation colle avec ce qu'il dit. Je comprends **une** ici dans son sens philosophique : l'image du futur (ainsi que la perspective du passé) est indivisible, elle forme un tout (Voir [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/une) A). Mais la question serait mieux sur https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Je ne suis pas certain que le titre de l'ouvrage soit «  Introduction à la philosophie *de **la*** histoire »

Comment: @None — J'abonde dans ce sens, on pourrait réécrire la phrase avec « … *[elle est] un**i**e à* la perspective … » ; deux extrémités *unies*, ne font/sont qu'*une* (pas de problème sur le sens :-). Pas vraiment d'accord pour le renvoi vers la philosophie,  même s'il est courant d'y rencontrer cette tournure, le petit Robert 1-B-3 *(nom masculin invariable dans les expressions ) : « Une seule et même chose… lui et son frère ne font qu'un … ()*. — PS : Je n'ai pas pu aller à plus d'une vingtaine de pages d'un autre livre de l'auteur qui était au programme…

Comment: philosophie **de l'histoire**.

Comment: L'image du futur naît de ce refus, une [image] comme la perspective sur le passé.

Comment: @Lambie *Une comme xxx* existe bien mais c'est du langage parlé/relâché. Cette ellipse est inconcevable ici. Le sens est celui qu'a donné None, avec [le bon lien](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/une/3).

Comment: Oui, le bon lien c'est celui que tu as donné, Pas le l'autre lien que dit A 1, adjectif.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec la réponse de None.

Comment: [Constitution](https://www.conseil-constitutionnel.fr/les-constitutions-dans-l-histoire/constitution-du-22-frimaire-an-viii): *La République française est une et indivisible*

Answer (score 0):

Reprenons: "ce qui est premier, c'est le refus du capitalisme et la volonté de le détruire. L'image du futur naît de ce refus, une comme la perspective sur le passé."

Le refus du capitalisme est le fondement de la vision de l'avenir, ainsi que la base de l'analyse du passé. Cette vision de l'histoire est UNE, au sens qu'elle est univoque, sans concession, également sans possibilité de contradiction au cas où votre interlocuteur disposerait d'un appareil policier pour vous empêcher de le contredire. Cette vue "UNE" est aussi un bloc indiscutable, applicable sous toutes les latitudes et dans toutes les situations.